# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am writing iPad application and created DatePickerView and calling it from UIPopoverController as below:

```
    DatePickerView *dt = [[DatePickerView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    popover =   [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:dt]; 
    popover.delegate = self;
    [dt release];

    self.popoverController = popover;
    [popover release];

    CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[sender frame] fromView:[sender superview]];    
    popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100);

    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

In the DatePickerView i have below code when the "Done" button is selected, this is basically sending the selected date with formatter back to main UI by using appdelegate:

.h
I

```
BOutlet UIDatePicker *dtPicker;

-(IBAction) btnSelectClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{

    MachineDetailsView *appDelegate;
    appDelegate = (MachineDetailsView *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];

    NSDate *dt = [dtPicker date];

    appDelegate.backPickerStartDate = [formatter stringFromDate:dt];
}
```

in MachineDetailsView i declared backPickerStartDate as below:

.h: file details

```
NSString *backPickerStartDate; 

UIPopoverController *popoverController; 

UIPopoverController *popover; 

....
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *backPickerStartDate;

....
```

.m: file details

```
@synthesize backPickerStartDate;
```

I am getting below error when i click on "Done" button of DatePickerView

```
2011-03-23 11:46:59.813 iMobile[22492:40b] -[iMobileAppDelegate setBackPickerStartDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a3dc00
2011-03-23 11:46:59.816 iMobile[22492:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[iMobileAppDelegate setBackPickerStartDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a3dc00'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00df9be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f4e5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dfb6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d6b366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d6af22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x00302a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x003911b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00393647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x003921f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x003270d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x0030837a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x0030d732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x0172fa36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00ddb064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00d3b6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00d38983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d38240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d38161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0172e268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x0172e32d GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x0031142e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  iG2Mobile                           0x000022f2 main + 84
    22  iG2Mobile                           0x00002295 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED. Please let me know if any further details are needed.

I also added below setter method to MachineDetailsView but still no use:

```
-(void)setBackPickerStartDate:(NSString *)newBackPickerStartDate
{

    if (backPickerStartDate != newBackPickerStartDate) {
        backPickerStartDate = newBackPickerStartDate;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stated that you've declared and synthesize the `backPickerStartDate` property in the `MachineDetailsView` class, yet you call it on an instance of `iMobileAppDelegate` in `btnSelectClicked:`

```
appDelegate.backPickerStartDate = [formatter stringFromDate:dt];
```

A few lines above, you have this:

```
MachineDetailsView *appDelegate;
appDelegate = (MachineDetailsView *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

That's wrong because you cast the pointer to your app delegate to a pointer to MachineDetailsView. That doesn't make your app delegate object magically turn into a MachineDetailsView object. What you need instead is a getter method or property that returns your MachineDetailsView object (or find another way to access it).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. IMobileAppDelegate contains UIWindow which actually contains a UISplitViewController. I am loading MachineDetailsView on the right side of the splitview and opening the Popover.

Comment: @user673673: So the splitview controller is responsible for MachineDetailsView ? Then it surely has an instance variable for it, doesn't it ? Make sure to expose it via a property. Then, for example, make sure there's a property or getter at your app delegate that can reach the splitview controller so that you can query appdelegate -> splitviewcontroller -> machinedetailsview. Or find another chain that you can make to reach the MachineDetailsView. Another possibility:

Comment: @user673673: ...  if you have a point that knows both your MachineDetailsView and your DatePickerView, then you can add a property to DatePickerView and assign the instance of the MachineDetailsView to it, so you can access the MachineDetailsView directly from inside the DatePickerView without the need of walking some object chain.

Comment: yes, i understand your point. I created a variable in DatePickerView which holds the reference to MachineDetailsView. using this reference variable I am able to send the selected date back to MachineDetailsView.

Answer (score 0):

```
[iMobileAppDelegate setBackPickerStartDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

As per the Exception above, you need to declare backPickerStartDate in your app delegate.